# MTOUCH error while releasing the xamarin.ios Project

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I am doing a project and it is building in iOS simulator and working fine.But while releasing the app i am getting the errors which are in the image.

[image]

I have been releasing the same even few days before.But unable to release this now. Can any of you please help me in resolving this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like you upgraded your Xamarin version or Xcode version without upgrading the other. Make sure eveyrthing is up-to-date, open your Xcode, make sure all the licenses are accepted and additional downloads are installed and try again.

Comment: Thanks for your response David.But the other projects are releasing well.Please help me in resolving my issue

Comment: Where does MKCluserAnnatation come from?